# Grafana gives error message' Server error' when trying to configure InfluxDB

Tags: raspberry-pi, grafana, influxdb

I'm creating a new user. Still, Grafana gives me an error

```raspberry
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.0
InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.0
> CREATE USER "todd" WITH PASSWORD '123456'
> CREATE DATABASE toddDb
> quit
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hostname -I
192.168.0.14
```

[image]

How do I get the frafana connection to InfluxDB working?

## EDIT

my conf file `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` is configured as following:

```
[http]

  # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true

  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  bind-address = ":8086"

  # Determines whether user authentication is enabled over HTTP/HTTPS.
  auth-enabled = true

  # Determines whether the pprof endpoint is enabled.  This endpoint is used for
  # troubleshooting and monitoring.
  pprof-enabled = true

  # Enables authentication on pprof endpoints. Users will need admin permissions
  # to access the pprof endpoints when this setting is enabled. This setting has
  # no effect if either auth-enabled or pprof-enabled are set to false.
  pprof-auth-enabled = true

  # Enables authentication on the /ping, /metrics, and deprecated /status
  # endpoints. This setting has no effect if auth-enabled is set to false.
  ping-auth-enabled = true
```

Comment: could you please configure `localhost:8086` as URL and check?

Comment: @hariK When changing to localhost I get the error: `Network Error: Bad Gateway(502)` InfluxDb and grafana is installed on raspberry (192.168.0.14). I am accessing the UI in the browser with my laptop (192.168.0.13). In my question above, I edited in my HTTP configuration.

Comment: I can also say that from Node-Red I am able to query data from InfluxDB. I have no Idea where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh that was a ridiculous problem.

In the `URL` field, the address needs to be prefixed with **`http://`**

Either `http://192.168.0.14:8086` or `http://localhost:8086` worked

[image]